# Cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'void Swap(double*, double*)'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to complete a review problem (for an upcoming programming final), however, I cannot get this problem worked out, as I continually get the error (title). I will post the question, and my attempted solution, as it's expected.

The Question:

you are given   the following   function    definition: 
void    swap(double *n1,    double  *n2)
for a   function    that    swaps   two numbers.    Implement   this    swap function   and 
call    the function    from    main,   passing in  two numbers.    Print   the values  for both
numbers in  main to verify  that    your    function    worked  correctly   and the 
numbers were    swapped.

My answer:

```
void Swap(double *n1, double *n2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *n1;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    *n1 = *n2;
    *n2 = temp;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    Swap(.99,2.1);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, we were given a solutions page, however, this was one of the problems that a solution was NOT given. What should I do/how do I approach this? Please explain any solutions given thoroughly! Thank you!

Comment: what do you expect from `Swap(.99,2.1)` from now on the value of 0.99 and 2.1 are swapped?

Comment: Hint: `double*` != `double`.

Comment: The two variables should merely swap - *n1 becoming *n2 and *n2 becoming the prior *n1

Comment: What variables? You call the function with two constants; there are no variables in sight. BTW, using an *integer* temporary in the Swap function is going to cause the *doubles* to be mangled.

Comment: Odd way to pass around references in C++.

Comment: @self - This was how we were instructed to do it-- I don't know if pointers are necessarily a requirement for this...but this is what was expected.

Comment: Are you trying to create a black hole? you're close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function parameter `double *n1` means that the function must be given the address of a double. However you tried to give it a double.

To take the address of a double, you have to create a variable:

```
double d1 = .99;
double d2 = 2.1;
Swap( &d1, &d2 );
```

Comment: Simple, and to the point! Thank you! I was reading through my C++ manual but was unable to connect the dots-- Pointers can be a real head-scratcher.

Comment: You also need to change the temporary in `Swap` to `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: After you understand what this function is doing, you should just use `using std::swap; swap(d1, d2);` in future projects.